# Display a custom field under short description in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, meta-boxes

In woocommerce I am using some code to add a Metabox with a custom field in product edit pages.

How can I display the value  of this custom field under short description in single product pages?

Here is my code:

```
add_action ('add_meta_boxes','add_info_meta_box');
function add_info_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box('new_meta', 'info','info_meta_fields_output','product', 'side');
}


function info_meta_fields_output($post)
{
    $new_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_new_meta',true);
    echo ('<label for="new_meta"> Custom Text </label>');
    echo ('<input type="text" id="new_meta" name="new_meta" value="'.esc_attr($new_meta).'"/>');
}

add_action('save_post','save_info_meta_box');
function save_info_meta_box($post_id)
{
    $new_meta=sanitize_text_field($_POST['new_meta']);
    update_post_meta ($post_id,'_new_meta',$new_meta);
}


// Displaying the value on single product pages
function meta_product($product_id) {

    $new_meta2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_new_meta', true);
    echo ('<p id="value-on-single-product">' . $new_meta2 . '</p>');
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meta_product',30);
```

But it doesn't display the custom field value.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** *(added a 2nd custom field as asked in comments)*

You should try the following, that will set your custom field in product general tab Metabox and will display this custom field value under product short description:

```
// Add the custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_field_to_general_product_metabox' );
function add_custom_field_to_general_product_metabox() {
    global $post;

    // Get the selected value
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_new_meta', true );
    if( empty( $value ) ) $value = ''; // Default value

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'       => 'new_meta',
        'label'    => __( 'Thông tin thêm', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'       => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'   => $value, // Displaying the selected value
    ) );


    // Get the selected value
    $value2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_new_meta2', true );
    if( empty( $value2 ) ) $value2 = ''; // Default value

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'       => 'new_meta2',
        'label'    => __( 'Thông tin thêm', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'       => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'   => $value2, // Displaying the selected value
    ) );
}

// Save the custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_field_to_general_product_metabox' );
function save_custom_field_to_general_product_metabox( $post_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['new_meta'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_new_meta', esc_attr( $_POST['new_meta'] ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['new_meta2'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_new_meta2', esc_attr( $_POST['new_meta2'] ) );
}


// Displaying the custom field value (on single product pages under short description)
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_custom_meta_field_value', 25 );
function display_custom_meta_field_value() {
    global $product;

    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_new_meta', true );
    if( ! empty( $custom_field ) )
        echo  '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . $custom_field . '</p>';

    $custom_field2 = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_new_meta2', true );
    if( ! empty( $custom_field2 ) )
        echo '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . $custom_field2 . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Hi, too pro.
How to hide id "p id =" value-on-single-product "when no data is entered and you can add a row of data to display more.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I'm using this code to display 2 custom fields.

Can somehow merge two into one, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using seperate, can you help me?                                                         
 // Add the custom field 1 and                                                                         
 // Add the custom field 2

Comment: I do not know how to include 2 custom fields as 1

Comment: Very fast, thank you.
I sent my expressions via gmail, but the answer was help. Thank you.
Next week I will Donate you.

Comment: @DucPhuli Ok it was a typo with one `}` to be removed … try it again… It works now (tested).

Comment: Thanks, it went into operation.
I'm trying to add a wrapper class tag, but it always appears when no custom fields are added. How do I display only when there are custom fields?
Thanks for the help.